# UIBUtton title animation for iPhone

Tags: xcode, animation, uibutton

I want to put an animation to custom UIButton's title so that the numbers (each title shows a random assigned number) will come rotating. How can i do that?

The problem is i don't want to do this using flipping number images. i am wondering if there is any other way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that you have a button called `flipLabelButton` connected as `IBOutlet` to your view controller, you can use this code to animate your button to a new label:

```
- (IBAction)flipLabelText:(id)sender {
    NSString *newText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", rand() % 100];
    [UIView beginAnimations:@"flipbutton" context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.flipLabelButton cache:YES];
    [self.flipLabelButton setTitle:newText forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
}
```